# escaping backslashes in python 3.4.5

Tags: python, string, escaping, backslash

As far as I thought, the following should work, however I get:

```
Python 3.4.5 (default, Nov  9 2016, 16:24:59)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat X.X.X-XX)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '\\'
'\\'
>>> '\'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    '\'
      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Am I missing something?

I'm expecting `'\\'` to return `\`.

Comment: why should it? You are escaping the quote and the string is missing its closing quote.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. `\'` is an escaped quote, *not* the end of the string.

Comment: And don't confuse the representation with the value! `'\\'` is the valid Python syntax to produce that value, so that's what Python echoes again. If it echoed `'\'` and you tried to copy and paste that you'd get the exact same `SyntaxError` exception you just created yourself!

Comment: So your question is how to print just one slash? (`'\'`)

Comment: Use `print('\\')` to see that the *value* contains just one character. Or use `len('\\')`. Or `'\\'[0]'`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm expecting '\\' to return \.

It does, if you `print` it.

At the interactive prompt it displays the `repr` to show you it is a string with a literal backslash in it.  This is for debugging. It'll show you `'\n'` instead of printing a blank line, too. `print` it and get a blank line.